# Split date range to year-month rows on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to create an output where I got one row per year-month.

Assume the dataset is:

```
id |        dateStart        |        dateEnd
1  | 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2015-03-31 00:00:00.000
2  | 2014-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2014-08-31 00:00:00.000
...
```

I need the following output:

```
id | year-month
1  |  2015-01
1  |  2015-02
1  |  2015-03
2  |  2014-07
2  |  2014-08
```

The output can be any datatype since I can just change that later.
That is for 2015-01 the following is ok, "2015-01-01 00:00:00.000", "2015-01-01", "201501", "2015 | jan" ect.

Note I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that uses recursive CTEs:

```
with CTE as (
      select id, dateStart as dte, dateEnd
      from t
      union all
      select id, dateadd(month, 1, dte), dateEnd
      from CTE
      where dateadd(month, 1, dte) < dateEnd
     )
select id, dte
from CTE;
```

You can convert the final result into any format you like.  For instance:

```
select id, year(dte) * 10000 + month(dte) as yyyymm_int
```

or

```
select id, cast(year(dte) * 10000 + month(dte) as varchar(255)) as yyyymm
```

Comment: @MartinCarlsson, you may need to add option of max recursion if intervals are greater then 100 months.

Comment: A big thing to note with this is that a recursive CTE is just syntactic sugar for a while loop and does not scale at all. Yes, in this case it doesn't matter because there are not many iterations, but what about the next person that reads this and applies the same logic to generate a list of numbers from 1 to 1,000,000 then writes a question wondering why their query is taking days. While the aim of the community is to answer questions and providing working solutions I believe we should also be promoting best practices.

Comment: Thanks. My source table will only grow to a few 1,000s and months are max 48. I'm adding MAXRECURSION as a safety valve in case of a mistake in the source table.

Comment: And for googlers wondering how to use MAXRECURSION, here you go: ... select id, dte
from CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100);

Comment: @MartinCarlsson, actually 100 is the default value and you didn't change anything with that statement...

Comment: @GarethD . . . Although this is undoubtedly slower than using a number table, the performance may not be that bad.  The final result is accumulating all the rows and the only extra overhead is in the CTE implementation.  There are definitely other circumstances where a recursive CTE would be bad, but I'm not sure this is a really bad case.

Answer (score 1):

Generate tally table(just make sure you get enough rows there). tally will contain values `0,1,2,.....n`. Then you do a join with condition adding thise values as months to `startDate` until it is greater then `endDate`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      dateStart DATETIME ,
      dateEnd DATETIME
    )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000' ),
        ( 2, '2014-07-01 00:00:00.000', '2014-08-31 00:00:00.000' )

;WITH cte AS(SELECT -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.m) m 
             FROM(VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))t1(m) CROSS JOIN 
                 (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))t2(m)) 
SELECT t.id, 
       DATEADD(mm, c.m, t.dateStart) AS year_month 
FROM cte c
JOIN @t t ON DATEADD(mm, c.m, t.dateStart) <= t.dateEnd
ORDER BY t.id, year_month
```

Output:

```
id  year_month
1   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
1   2015-02-01 00:00:00.000
1   2015-03-01 00:00:00.000
2   2014-07-01 00:00:00.000
2   2014-08-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world you would have a [calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/), then your query would simply be:

```
SELECT  t.id,
        c.FirstDayOfMonth
FROM    YourTable AS t
        INNER JOIN dbo.Calendar c
            ON c.FirstDayOfMonth >= t.DateStart
            AND c.FirstDayOfMonth <= t.DateEnd
            AND c.DayOfMonth = 1;
```

Assuming that you don't have a calendar table then you can do it with a list of numbers generated on the fly (Read [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) for more on this). The following will generate a list from 1-10,000:

```
WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N3.N) FROM N3)
SELECT * FROM Numbers;
```

Then you can join this to your original table:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id INT, DateStart DATE, DateEnd DATE);
INSERT @T (ID, DateStart, DateEnd)
VALUES (1, '20150101', '20150331'), (2, '20140701', '20140831');

WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N3.N) FROM N3)

SELECT  t.ID,
        [year-month] = DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number + DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.DateStart), 0)
FROM    @T AS t
        INNER JOIN Numbers AS N
            ON N.Number - 1 <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, t.DateStart, t.DateEnd);
```